# blueprintcss, Two Span-12s inside One Span-24?

Tags: css, block, html, blueprint-css

I'm using a span-24 div as full-width page and i have some other span-24s inside that one. But i want to have two span-12s side-by-side inside the main span-24. When i try this, they end up on top of each other. Here is my code -

```
<div id="content" class="span-24">
   <div id="main" class="span-24" role="main">
      <div class="container">   
   <div class = "span-24">
   <div id = "block_"><h2>Popular Posts</h2></div>  
   </div>   

   <div class = "span-12">

   <div id = "block_"><h2>Best Users</h2></div>      </div>
   <div class = "span-12">
   <div id = "block_"><h2>Popular Forum Posts</h2></div>      </div>
  </div>
  </div><!-- /#main -->
```

Comment: Please show your css classes where you define these styles.

Answer (score 2):

on the second `span-12` give it also a `last` class to remove the right margin..

```
<div class = "span-12 last">
```

Comment: How do i use this method when there are 3 or more?

Comment: @user, only the last one requires it, regardless of the number of columns you need. Provided ofcourse that you use the appropriate `span-?` that fits in the container.. for example for 3 spans you would use in your case `.span-8` `.span-8` `.span-8 last`

Answer (score 1):

Set spans to be inline-block.

```
.span-12{
display:inline-block;
}
```